# Android device login to php/mysql website for syncing

Tags: php, android

Im going to make an app that will be able to sync data between android mobile phone and a webpage database. At the moment im trying to think things through and figure out the hard parts. The first thing that crosses my mind is the login part.

The best idea i have is that before starting my app user has to log in. When he logs in it sends user data to my web page and it returns true/false. If it returns true i make somekind of an session in my app that says i am logged in (to access app features) but also stores my username and password. Now if i press the sync button or do something else that will need communication with my webside i can check the user/password every time. Because on the web site im planning to do different actions (login, sync, something else) i need to check the login every time - otherwise a third party could just access sync action without actually logign in first.

Anyway, that my thoughts at the moment. Im sure ill ask more detailed questions when i get to coding (im a beginner with android/java) but at the moment i wish to know if the idea of the thing is good or can it be done smarter/better?

Thank you.

Comment: The pattern you described is pretty standard. Just don't start from scratch. There are plenty examples of good RESTful APIs, and there are php classes to implement those, as well as Java clients you can use in Android.

Comment: Mobile users aren't going to want to log in repeatedly. Register them instead. Put their id on their phone in private storage or shared preferences and use that to access their account. Also be prepared to help them find their account if they change phones, reinstall, or clear storage. Also, if you are using MySQL on your own site, make sure you secure the site file structure. Maybe even encrypt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suggesting you to create API based application so you won't be troubled if you want to create it in many platform (in case you also want to create in iOS).

What I'm usually used is using API_KEY. API_KEY is a random number generated by the PHP side to save the login session of the user. When the user login from the mobile phone (sends the username and the password) the PHP side will generate API_KEY and updatethe existing API_KEY (if the user have logged in before in other device) in the web database so the login session in the other device will be automatically expired but you must add API_KEY validation everytime you try to access the the database (sync your application) or if you want more strict you can do the checking everytime the user change the screen.

If you have some question about this feel free to ask in the comment ! :)